# Ruby way to check if a string is not blank?

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to check if a variable is not blank in an else if condition in Ruby (not Rails)?

```
elsif not variable.to_s.empty?
  # do something
end
```

or

```
elsif !variable.to_s.empty?
  # do something
end
```

or

```
elsif variable.to_s.length > 0
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Each of these ways should work. Are you asking which way is best?

Comment: The second one is most idiomatic, I think. If you were using rails, you could also do `if variable.present?` or `if !variable.blank?`, which handle both empty strings and nils.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
string = ""

unless string.to_s.strip.empty?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: @goldylucks In case you know that vatriable contains string. But variable can be nil instead and in this case strip will produce error.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out that `''.empty?` returns `true` but `'  '.empty?` returns `false`. Even `to_s.length` for `'  '` is not zero.

Maybe it is better to use strip as `'  '.strip.empty?`

Answer (score 5):

You can use either

```
unless var.empty?
  #do sth
end
```

or

```
unless var == ""
  #do sth
end
```

or all of these with `if` and a negator `!`.

Comment: Both will fail if var is nil.

Comment: that wasn't part of the question. To check that simply do: `unless var && var.empty?`.

Comment: That's what `.to_s` is there for (in the original post) - to handle nils.

Answer (score 4):

The source of the `empty?` method is analogous to the following:

```rb
def empty?
    return length == 0      
end
```

So, you can safely use

```rb
any_string.length != 0
```

Anyway, using that code inside an else if is a bit verbose, I would encourage you to define the `present?` method inside the `String` class.

```rb
class String
    def present?
        !empty?
    end
end
```

Now you can write your code the following way:

```rb
if some_condition
  # do something
elsif variable.to_s.present?
  # do something else
end
```

This way you get a clear code, without using `negations` or `unless` who are hard to read.

Of course, there is one problem here, I took the `present?` name (and method) from Rails.  `present?` returns true if the object is not blank, but strings with tabs or spaces (white characters) are considered blanks. So, this `present?` will return true to for the following strings:

```
"".present?       # => false
"   ".present?    # => true
"\t\n\r".present? # => true
" blah ".present? # => true
```

It depends on what you want, high chances are that you want to get true for the first 3 strings, and false for the later. You could use @RamanSM approach and use `strip` to avoid empty spaces

```rb
class String
    def present?
        !strip.empty?
    end
end
```

now, `present?` returns false for strings with white spaces

```
"".present?       # => false
"   ".present?    # => false
"\t\n\r".present? # => false
" blah ".present? # => true
```

Note: Consider that `String.present?` is present in the ActiveSupport library (which ships with rails) if you add ActiveSupport or use Rails you should use ActiveSupport implementation instead.

Comment: Should call it 'any?' to match what happens for lists and other collections. Also... ugh: patching top-level classes.

Comment: @TimBaverstock Alternative proposal are appreciated.

Comment: Haha. My alternative proposals would not be considered constructive. :)

Comment: `''.present?` raises `undefined method 'present?' for "":String (NoMethodError)` unless you include `ActiveSupport` which is not a part of core ruby

Comment: @jedi read the whole answer please, it provides the implementation of `present?` so you don't have to include ActiveSupport and plenty of examples.

Comment: @lcjury but you shouldn't propose this solution because monkey patching is something you should do only when you really have to and when you know what you're doing. In this case they should add `ActiveSupport`. What if they later add `ActiveSupport`? They will overwrite and eventually break `ActiveSupport#present?` method.

Comment: I added a note at the end of my answer for people to be careful about its usage. I have a different opinion on monkey patching. Hopefully it would help some people in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `if` to `unless`...

If you **know** your variable will be a String...`if str[0]`

With nil check...`if str && str[0]` OR `if str&.[](0)` (I prefer the latter but it might look odd to some people and requires Ruby >= 2.3).

Also...I'd be very careful about calling `#to_s` on anything because you could end up with unexpected results. If `str` turns out to be something that you weren't expecting...

```
str = false
str.to_s[0] # => 'f' (i.e. truthy)
str.to_s.empty? # => false

str = nil
str.to_s[0] # => nil (i.e. falsey)
str.to_s.empty? # => true
```

I think this caution applies to usage of `#to_s` in the other answer here as well. Exceptions can be your friend.

Answer (score -1):

For the string (say abc) which is not defined/undefined we should check for `abc.nil?`
otherwise abc.blank? will throw (NoMethodError) undefined method `empty?` for nil:NilClass error